# Front crankshaft bolt removal

Tags: transmission, torque, crankshaft

The front crankshaft bolt, that secures the harmonic balancer, which is also the driving pulley of the drive belt, is 184 ft/lbs on my Tacoma. The Haynes manual says to use a pin spinner to lock the balancer/pulley in place while untwisting the bolt. Since I didn't have a pin spinner that matched, I just shifted in 1st speed and turned the bolt counterclockwise with a long breaker bar and a pipe over it to use as an extension.

Can doing it like that put too much pressure on the transmission?

Comment: We used to wedge the bar ans socket against the chassis and flick the starter - easy, just make sure it does not fly through the radiator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider what the torque output of the V6 is in your Tacoma. This is far in excess of the 184 lb-ft the bolt on your crankshaft bolt. The transmission can stand up to a lot more than what that bolt can.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, if the torque is too much it would effectively move the car since it is geared.

**From Wikipedia:**
There were a total of three engines available for the Toyota Tacoma: 2.4 L four-cylinder rated at 142 hp (106 kW) and 160 lb⋅ft (217 N⋅m) of torque 2.7 L four-cylinder rated at 150 hp (112 kW) and 177 lb⋅ft (240 N⋅m) of torque 3.4 L V6 rated at 190 hp (142 kW) and 220 lb⋅ft (298 N⋅m) of torque.

So let's say you have the 190hp engine which produces 220lb-ft, that's more than 184 lb-ft you would apply to that bolt. Numbers aside, if you select any gear and rotate the crankshaft "hard enough" it would just move the car as it was the engine itself. I recently rebuilt a classic Fiat 50, to manipulate the damper's nut I had to not only put 1st but also hand brake and a wedge in the front wheels because otherwise the car would move around :) In the manual they show a teeth tool that should be fixed against the flywheel, but we don't have such. I have seen other methods, like using a strong screwdriver to lock the flywheel.